# Why fdsymbol conflicts with \mapstochar?

Tags: fdsymbol

This code:

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\begin{document}
$\mapstochar\relbar\mathrel{\mkern-12mu}\mapsto$
\end{document}
```

gives this:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \mapstochar

l.4 $\mapstochar
                \relbar\mathrel{\mkern-12mu}\mapsto$
```

However, if I remove `\usepackage{fdsymbol}` -- it compiles just fine. What's the problem and how to solve? I do need both `fdsymbol` and `\mapstochar`

Comment: Why are you using `fdsymbol`? From the manual: “FdSymbol is a font of mathematical symbols designed as a companion to Typotheque’s Fedra family, but it might also fit well to other contemporary typefaces.” The key is “might”; actually it's visually incompatible with most other fonts.

Comment: the style contains `\let\mapstochar\undefined`.

Comment: The same happens if I use `MnSymbol` package... Why they all hate `\mapstochar` so much? :)

Comment: Looks like yet another case where you have to understand what the source code does and selectively copy parts of it around then.

Comment: There are, unfortunately, too many answers that suggest to load `fdsymbol` or `MnSymbol` in order to get some new symbols. Why “unfortunately”? Because both packages provide symbols that are visually incompatible with most math fonts.

Comment: mnsymbol and fdsymbol are essentially the same, they both swap out the entire symbol collection with a different collection in different encoding. So you should not "expect" any symbol command to still work, Of course by design, as many as possible symbols are mapped to names matching amssymb, but it should be no surprise that some do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following experiment.

```
\documentclass{acmart}
%\usepackage{fdsymbol}

\begin{document}

%$\mapstochar\relbar\mathrel{\mkern-12mu}\mapsto$

$A\to B\otimes C$

$X\mapsto Y\cong Z$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now uncomment the `fdsymbol` line and the output you get changes to

[image]

The situation is no better if you replace `fdsymbol` with `MnSymbol`

[image]

which is hardly what the copy editors at ACM would like to see. The ACM hired Boris Veytsman (who currently also serves as the president of TUG) in order to have a document class replacing the plethora of classes written in the years to satisfy the needs of that ACM journal or conference. This way the ACM is able to ensure uniformity in all of its published documents.

If I were in charge of accepting or rejecting a submission, one that has the symbols shown above would be rejected. And I don't think it would just be me.

The objection that `fdsymbol` provides many more symbols than `amssymb` is invalid. The package indeed has many symbols, but the price to have them is possible rejection of a submission, besides the document look more like a patchwork than a typographically sound piece of work.

Now, what would be your symbol with the `acmart` fonts? The code you use isn't really good in this case, but the following would

```
\documentclass{acmart}

\begin{document}

$A\mapsto B$

$A\mathrel{\mkern2mu}\mapstochar\mathrel{\mkern-2mu}\mapsto B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

This exploits the fact that `\mapstochar` has zero width (in the standard setting, which is followed by the Libertine math fonts). With Computer Modern the output would be

[image]

Now, if you really want to do the same with `fdsymbol`, you can't use `\mapstochar`, that doesn't exist. But you can handcraft it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\mapstochar}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\mapstochar@\relax}}
\newcommand{\mapstochar@}[2]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \clipbox{0 0 {0.8\width} 0}{$\m@th#1\mapsto$}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\dblmapsto}{%
  \mathrel{\mkern2mu}\mapstochar\mathrel{\mkern-2mu}\mapsto
}

\begin{document}

$A\mapsto B$

$A\dblmapsto B$

\end{document}
```

[image]