# How to draw a line with a label over a math segment, without the use of \overlinesegment from MnSymbol?

Tags: mnsymbol

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\newcommand*{\ohat}[2]{%
  \stackrel{\textcolor{gray}{#1}}{%
    \textcolor{gray}{%
      \overlinesegment{\textcolor{black}{%
        \vrule height 8pt depth 1pt width 0pt%
        #2%
      }}%
    }%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
$x = 42 \times \ohat{y}{5 + 8}$
\end{document}
```

It renders as such:

[image]

Is it possible to do the same, but without `MnSymbol`? This package conflicts with `amssymb` and a few other `ams*` packages, as [discussed here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/662698).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's acceptable to use one-sided rather than two-sided brackets, the `\overbracket` macro of the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package may be of interest to you.

In the following, I employ the `\overbracket` macro to define a user macro called `\ohat`, which sets `gray` as the default "color" for the overbracket and the material to be shown above the bracket. E.g., `$x = 42 \times \ohat{5+8}{y}$`. The default color can be overridden by specifying an alternate color as the optional argument; e.g., `$x = 42 \times \ohat[blue]{5+8}{z}$`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\acmConference{}{}{}   % just for this example
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \overbracket macro
\usepackage{xcolor}    % for \textcolor macro

\newcommand\ohat[3][gray]{%
   \overbracket[0.4pt][2pt]{\textcolor{black}{#2}}^{\color{#1}#3}}
   
\begin{document}
$x = 42 \times \ohat{5+8}{y}$

\medskip
$x = 42 \times \ohat[blue]{5+8}{z}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps to import the needed symbol.

First look at the definition of `\overlinesegment`

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\overlinesegment}{\mathpalette{\overarrow@\linesegmentfill@}}
```

This shows that the command uses the same infrastructure as `\xrightarrow`. OK, now we need `\linesegmentfill@`

```
\def\linesegmentfill@{\arrowfill@\leftfootline\relbar\rightfootline}
```

OK, we need `\leftfootline` and `\rightfootline`.

```
\Decl@Mn@Char\rightfootline          {MnSyA}{\mathrel}
\Decl@Mn@Char\upfootline             {MnSyA}{\mathrel}
\Decl@Mn@Char\leftfootline           {MnSyA}{\mathrel}
\Decl@Mn@Char\downfootline           {MnSyA}{\mathrel}
```

Well, `MnSymbol` isn't very friendly, because it just lists the symbols and automatically steps the slot numbers. Not difficult to work around, because we can ask TeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\show\rightfootline
\show\leftfootline
\stop
```

and the console will tell you

```
> \rightfootline=\mathchar"3478
> \leftfootline=\mathchar"347A.
```

We know need to find `MnSyA`.

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyA}         {U}  {MnSymbolA}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{MnSyA}       {bold}{U}  {MnSymbolA}{b}{n}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}  {MnSymbolA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolA5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolA6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolA7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolA8
   <9-10> MnSymbolA9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA10
  <12->   MnSymbolA12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{b}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolA-Bold5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolA-Bold6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolA-Bold7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolA-Bold8
   <9-10> MnSymbolA-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA-Bold10
  <12->   MnSymbolA-Bold12}{}
```

We have all we need.

```
\documentclass{acmart}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}  {MnSymbolA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolA5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolA6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolA7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolA8
   <9-10> MnSymbolA9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA10
  <12->   MnSymbolA12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{b}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolA-Bold5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolA-Bold6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolA-Bold7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolA-Bold8
   <9-10> MnSymbolA-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA-Bold10
  <12->   MnSymbolA-Bold12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyA}         {U}  {MnSymbolA}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{MnSyA}       {bold}{U}  {MnSymbolA}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rightfootline}{\mathrel}{MnSyA}{"78}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftfootline}{\mathrel}{MnSyA}{"7A}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\overlinesegment}{\mathpalette{\overarrow@\linesegmentfill@}}
\def\linesegmentfill@{\arrowfill@\leftfootline\relbar\rightfootline}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\ohat}[2]{%
  \overset{\textcolor{gray}{#1}}{%
    \colorlet{currentcolor}{.}%
    \textcolor{gray}{%
      \overlinesegment{\textcolor{currentcolor}{%
        \vrule height 8pt depth 1pt width 0pt
        #2%
      }}%
    }%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
$x = 42 \times \ohat{y}{5 + 8}$
\end{document}
```

Note `\overset` and not `\stackrel` and the better color management, so the macro will also work if the current color isn't black.

[image]